# Internal server error 500 while using application

Tags: python-3.x, django, iis-7, iis-7.5

Please find below event viewer log,can anyone help me why am getting this error(sometimes)

Environment details:

- Django framework
- IIS application
- Python 3.7

```
Faulting application name: python.exe, version: 3.7.3150.1013, time stamp: 0x5c9954fa
Faulting module name: _ctypes.pyd, version: 3.7.3150.1013, time stamp: 0x5c9954c9
Exception code: 0xc0000005
Fault offset: 0x000000000000f365
Faulting process id: 0x1938
Faulting application start time: 0x01d839ca6dc31b14
Faulting application path: D:\qm_env\Scripts\python.exe
Faulting module path: d:\python37\DLLs\_ctypes.pyd
Report Id: 8701a9d7-3cc9-4a91-b8c5-ff04fb2b2a59**
Faulting package full name:
Faulting package-relative application ID:
```

Comment: Internal server error 500 while using any backend means there is an error from your backend, kindly check your powershell very seriously, it would be displaying some kind of error or warning, it is not from any cdn or plugin, always remember.

Comment: What is the lib `DLLs_ctypes.pyd`? How you apply it in application and publish to IIS? Did you put it in site root folder or any other folders, and did IIS app pool have permission to read write it. Code 0xc0000005 usually means a pool permission issue. Another thing, does windows defender remind that this is an insecurity file?

Comment: The event log entry tells us nothing useful. It's just a typical Python executable crash and due to native memory access violation (what `0xc0000005` means). It will be difficult to debug further into that, as you have to be familiar with a tool like WinDbg and have all the necessary symbol files.